# row to column Transposed. issue with the record

Tags: c#, transpose

This is my table i get from database:

```
 **Month        PCode         Sales**
January        001           2
January        002           1
January        003           5
February       001           6
February       002           4
February       003           2
March          001           8
March          002           10
March          003           7
```

Result that i want:

```
**Month           001       002      003**
January           2         1        5     
February          6         4        2
March             8        10        7
```

What i did so far:

```
private void TransposeTable(DataTable inputTable)
{
    DataTable outputTable = new DataTable();

    outputTable.Columns.Add(inputTable.Columns[0].ColumnName.ToString());

    List<string> l_month = new List<string>();

    foreach (DataRow inRow in inputTable.Rows)
    {
        if (!l_month.Contains(inRow[1].ToString())) //if PCode not found
        {
             l_month.Add(inRow[1].ToString());
             outputTable.Columns.Add(inRow[1].ToString());//PCode as column header
        }
    }
}
```

I already create the table column by using the code above, now i having problem on how to transpose the sales

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a new "pivot" `DataTable`, with the unique `PCode` values as the columns, you are going to need to do it in a few steps:

```
private DataTable TransposeTable(DataTable inputTable)
{
    // create output pivot table and add the "Month" column to it.
    var pivotTable = new DataTable("PivotTable");
    var srcMonthCol = inputTable.Columns["Month"];
    var salesDataType = inputTable.Columns["Sales"].DataType;
    pivotTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(srcMonthCol.ColumnName, srcMonthCol.DataType));

    // get unique 'PCode' values
    var uniquePeriods = inputTable.AsEnumerable()
        .Select(x => x.Field<string>("PCode"))
        .Distinct()
        .ToList();

    // Add the unique 'PCode' as columns to the pivot table
    uniquePeriods.ForEach(p => pivotTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(p, salesDataType)));

    // Now we have the columns for the pivot table set-up and we need
    // to get the rows, which will be grouped by month.
    var rows = inputTable.AsEnumerable()
        .GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("Month"))
        .Select(x => {
            var mc = new object[] { x.Key, };
            var salesCols = uniquePeriods
                .Select(p => x
                    .Where(r => r.Field<string>("PCode") == p)
                    .Select(r => r["Sales"])
                    .FirstOrDefault());
            return mc.Concat(salesCols).ToArray();
        }).ToList();

    // Now we can add the rows.
    rows.ForEach(r => pivotTable.Rows.Add(r));

    // And return the result.
    return pivotTable;
}
```

**Notes**

- If the only reason you are using the `inputTable` is as an intermediary to construct a pivot table, it could be more efficient to directly query the database for the information needed to create the pivot.
- If there can be multiple sales entries per period / per month, this will not work as expected, and summing of the sales values along one of these axes will be needed.

Answer (score 0):

You may aggregate DataTable records and build pivot table report from C# with free [NReco.PivotData library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NReco.PivotData/):

```
DataTable inputTable; // your input data
var pivotData = new PivotData(
    new string[] {"Month","PCode"},
    new SumAggregatorFactory("Sales"),
    new DataTableReader(inputTable) );
```

at this step you'll get in-memory multi-dimensional dataset (values can be accessed by indexer). 
Next step is getting pivot table with with PivotTable class:

```
var pvtTbl = new PivotTable(
    new[] {"Month"},   // dimension(s) used for rows
    new [] {"PCode"},  // dimension(s) used for columns
    pivotData);
```

After that you can use pvtTbl for generating pivot table report simply by iterating by columns ( `PivotTable.ColumnKeys`, `PivotTable.RowsKeys` + get cell value by row/column indexes like `pvtTbl[0,0]` ) and rows (you can download MVC example that generates HTML pivot table on PivotData library official page).

I'm author of this library; feel free to ask me if you have any complications in using it.

Comment: I believe you forgot to disclose in your answer that you are the owner and author of the library that you are recommending in your answer.

Comment: Most of your answers (12 out of the last 13 that I checked) relate to third party libraries with which you are affiliated and where you have not disclosed your affiliation in the answer. Please refer to [How to not be a spammer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): **you *must* disclose your affiliation in your answers** and edit your answers to include disclosure of your affiliation with the recommended libraries.

Comment: Alex, thank you for noticing about that (I've added a notice that I'm an author of this library. Hope this is not a problem since library is free for use and I believe it might be useful for users who looking for simple solution to build pivot table in C#.